# Executing Controller Action from View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails (RoR).  I created a new method on my controller.  I want to  call the new method from a view.

On my view, I have this code:

```
<%= link_to "MyMethod", :method=>:MyMethod %>
```

When I click on the link, the URL changes to `http://localhost:3000/seats?method=MyMethod`, and the page reloads on the browser and from the log I can see that `MyMethod` is never executed.

What can I do to call a method from a view?

Comment: Architecturally, your view is not supposed to call methods on your controller. Find some other place to put the code you want to call, such as a view helper.

Answer (score 0):

Ops... the method thing, is not for calling a method but to describe an HTTP method.
OK, so I shouldn't be using method.
If i use :action=>"MyMethod"

the URL becomes
seat/mymethod

which produces error, cannot find seat with id=mymethod
how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to lie within your routes (or you actually need a view helper as ndp suggests).

If a route is a better fit, go over the excellent [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). I can imagine one of two solutions:

- `map.resources :the_resource, :member => { :my_method => :get }`: Use this if the method acts on one instance of the_resource. The URL would end up as follows: `/the_resource/:id/my_method`.
- `map.resources :the_resource, :collection => { :my_method => :get }`: Use this if :my_method acts on many instances of the_resource - a collection. The URL would end up as: `/the_resource/my_method`.

Then run `rake routes | grep my_method`. What you'll find is the routing helpers generated by rails to access this method. You would call them either via my_method_the_resource(@an_instance) - for the member case, or my_method_the_resources for the collection case.

More information on section 3.11 of the linked guide.

Answer (score 0):

assuming 'mymethod' was in a controller named 'users' and was pointing to an action 'mymethod'
in your routes.rb add this:

map.my_method '/mymethod', :controller => 'users', :action => 'mymethod'

then in your view you can call it like this: